# Ubuntu 22.04 & 22.10 on Virtual machine is extremely slow (same behaviour on VMware, Parallels or VirtualBox)

Tags: 22.04, virtualization

Ubuntu 22.04 & 22.10 on Virtual machines is extremely slow (VMware, Parallels or VirtualBox)

Ubuntu 20.04 has no issues. I have no idea what might have got introduced in 22.04 and 22.10.The CPU or memory consumption looks pretty normal.

My VM specs:

- 21GB Ram
- 8 cores Processor
- 3d Graphics Accelerated - ON or OFF does not make any difference
- 200GB SSD

Applications Open:

- Couple of instances of Intellij
- 6 docker containers running in the background.

Once again there is plenty of CPU and RAM available. But the system is very sluggish. Opening folders and navigating to other locations is extremely slow. Think something is eating up the disk reading bandwidth. Intellij has very slow indexing.

Comment: slow compared to what? Virtualization will *always* be slower than running an OS natively. What are you comparing to? And it sounds like file access is the only "slow" thing, since all the things you described are disk access-limited. Did you check what is accessing the hard drive constantly?

Comment: @Esther - Well. as mentioned in my description it is slow compared to a 20.04 VM. I'm not comparing it to OS natively. I understand it will be slower on VM.

Comment: sorry, I missed that. Did you check disk usage and which programs are using the disk?

Comment: no worries at all. Let me check on the disk and get back to you shortly.

Comment: some people have reported issues with ubuntu 22.04 host, windows guest, on 5.15.0-generic-47 kernel, maybe try downgrading the guest kernel to -46 and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *kinetic* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 13 October 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 20 October 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/kinetic-kudu-release-schedule/27263  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *kinetic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: FYI: You mention three OS version from three different *development* cycles; 20.04 was the LTS and conclusion of the 18.10->20.04 cycle; 22.04 LTS being the LTS and conclusion of the 20.10->22.04 cycle; and 22.10 (*kinetic*) the first non-LTS (of 3) before the final 22.04 LTS in the current *development* cycle. A full *development* cycle has 3 non-LTS releases & completes with the LTS release; ie. has 4 mini-cycles within it,  however *kinetic* and its 5.19 kernel & software stack is **off-topic** on this site until release in October.

Comment: oh ok.. would you recommend staying with 20.04 then?

Comment: Same problem here with Lubuntu 22.04. Happened after I upgraded. 3d acceleration is working but everything feels very sluggish and also suddenly rendering issues in VSCode which go away when running it without gpu acceleration.

Answer (score 2):

I use Virtual machine with configuration: 16G RAM, 4CPU, 100G SSD. And try these 2 ways:

- Install Ubuntu 22.04, then turn on 3d acceleration, 128MB Video memory. ==> Then using VSCode is very jerky and laggy.
- Turn on 3d acceleration, Video memory 128MB, Then install Ubuntu 22.04 (select 3rd party software for graphics) ==> Then use VSCode quite well, no lag feeling.
  Hope to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I turned OFF 3d Acceleration in the VM Settings to fix the problems for my Ubuntu 22.04 Server Guest VM.  I did the same for my Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop Guest VM, but I mostly use this VM as a server.

Answer (score 0):

May be a simple mistake but have you mounted the guest additions iso? Once I enabled 3d acceleration and installed and updated my guest additions on oracle VBOX 22.04 is like butter for me. 128mb/500gb(dynamically allocated on a 1tb external ssd/4 processors. As well as for 3d acceleration to be on you need to change the graphics controller to VMSVGA. you can check this by installing nux-tools to see if the 3d acceleration is actually functioning. Good luck!

Comment: I switched back to 20.04. But I am pretty sure I don't usually have that iso always mounted. I am using VMWare Workstation.

Answer (score 0):

My experience was this: during the installation in VirtualBox it was so slow that I had to wait minutes for each step of the installation. I tried to activate the 3D acceleration and assigned 8Gb of RAM. The speed compared to the 20.04 LTS version is now acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while using the settings of Ubuntu version 22 in Oracle Virtual Box 6.1 General Tab - "General","Basic","version"  where I was trying with the default option "Ubuntu-64". While it was configuring the Ubuntu for first time, the installation stuck.
But as I changed this option to "Linux 2.6 / 3.x / 4.x (64 - bit ) it worked like charm. Again I reboot its working like its hanged.

I backed up the installed VM, uninstalled Oracle Virtual Box 6.1 and installed latest Oracle Virtual Box 7, restored the backed VM in newly installed Oracle Virtual Box and now its working properly.

I have done fresh installation on Oracle VM 7 version, there is no issue at all.

This is always related to the updates of software.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Manoj Sule

Answer (score 0):

Turning on acceleration solved my interface slow response problems. My graphics memory was 256M. I increased that to 512M. I think I needed more graphics RAM to push to a 4k monitor.